# Query result from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables named User, Review and Business. I want to select out the **business_name**, review **content** and **review_id** using **user_id** and **business_id**?

I can do this separately:

`SELECT business_name FROM Business WHERE business_id = 'XXXXX'`

`SELECT review_id, content FROM Review WHERE business_id = 'XXXXX' AND user_id = 'XXXX'`

The question is how do I combine the result together? that I get achieve

`SELECT review_id, content, business_name FROM ...`

User table

```
user_id 
username 
password 
email 
date_created 
last_login 
dob
```

Review table

```
review_id
user_id
business_id
rating
content
post_date
```

Business table

```
business_id 
business_name
country
city
email
date_created
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the table together.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 'SELECT 
    a.user_id, b.content, b.review_id, c.business_id, c.business_name 
    FROM userTable a 
    LEFT JOIN ReviewTable b on a.user_id=b.user_id
    LEFT JOIN BusinessTable c on b.business_id=c.business_id
    WHERE CLAUSE'

Comment: Do some thing like this. @frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could achieve this by executing this query:

```
SELECT a.business_name, b.review_id, b.content 
FROM Business a, Review b 
WHERE a.business_id = "XXXX" AND a.business_id=b.business_id AND b.user_id ="XXXX" ;
```

You could image this in steps:

1. First you select a certain Business name with id "XXXX" from business table
2. Then you select all of the reviews for this Business id from Reviews table
3. You filter only those reviews with user with id "XXXX"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inner join on the three tables User and Review table joined using user_id and Review and Business table using Business_id.

Then provide user_id and business_id specific values as per your need.